# Celery tasks not throwing exception in Django Tests

Tags: python, django, testing, celery, celery-task

I have a couple of celery tasks that are included in my Django tests. Unfortunately exceptions are not thrown when tasks are invoked via *.delay()*. I am setting [CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-always-eager) to True.

**tasks.py**

```
import celeryapp as app

@app.task()
def exception_task():
    print 'CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER:', app.conf['CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER']
    raise Exception('foo')
```

**tests.py**

```
def test_exception_in_task(self):
        from tasks import exception_task
        exception_task.delay()
```

**Output**

```
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER: True
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.686s
```

When removing the *.delay* the test exits with an error as excpected:

```
ERROR: test_exception_in_task
Exception: foo
```

**Versions**

```
celery==3.1.4
Django==1.6.4
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems I additionally had to set [CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-eager-propagates) to True.

**Celery >=5.3.1** it is `CELERY_TASK_EAGER_PROPAGATES`.

Comment: This still works with Celery 5.

Comment: Celery 5.3.1, I had to use `CELERY_TASK_EAGER_PROPAGATES`. Is it me or does Celery change this stuff every other release?

Answer (score 5):

Under celery 4.0, I had to use [CELERY_TASK_EAGER_PROPAGATES](https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/4061/files#diff-cc90971f3ec1a23279b1aa3e1426d247R123)

Answer (score 0):

```
@override_settings(task_always_eager=True, task_eager_propagates=True)
def test_my_task(self):
    pass
```

is what worked for me using Celery 5.

Documentation on config name changes: https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html